# Convert List<Integer> to JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

How can I convert a List object in Java to a JSON object?

For example, how can I convert this:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2):
...
```

To this JSON:

```
{
    "List" : [1, 2, ...]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to convert to String use the  `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Ex:

```
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(2);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myList);
            System.out.println("result = " + json);
            //System.out.println(json);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            //
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want just to convert the list to json, you can use Gson:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
String json = new Gson().toJson(myList);
```

If you want that the key will be "List", you need to create a object with a member that call List and then convert it.